# Running a windows console application on Linux debian server

Tags: linux, windows

I was wondering if it is possible to run a windows console application (.exe) on linux (server no GUI).

I looked into Wine but you need a GUI for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run it with `wineconsole` instead. For example:

```
wineconsole gwbasic.exe
```

If you don't have a GUI then this will simply use the terminal as you expect, though it will take advantage of the GUI if you have one.

Note that if you receive the message that "Application tried to create a window, but no driver could be loaded." it means your "console" application is *actually* a GUI application and requires a GUI. In this case consider running it in a virtual X server such as Xvfb.

Comment: The console-application also includes a .dll file and a .db file. Will this work too?

Comment: Wine can use some DLL if in the same directory, but is it for a production server ? It's like running an app off a old nt4 in my opinion, just use a windows box

Comment: @MichaelHampton Nevermind, wine handles this too.